# Two Tube light fixtures (with a single switch) flickering

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture

We had 2 light fixtures changed in our basement two years ago. Both fixtures worked with a single switch. In place of each single bulb fixture, a new tube light fixture was put in (each fixture had 1 pair of tube lights). Since then, we have had to replace all the tube lights twice. The fixtures were new and from a standard manufacturer (Philips) and so were the tube lights, the ballast that was replaced was also from the same manufacturer. The tubes flickered and stopped working. We changed the ballast on one of the fixtures where the flickering problem occurred first, but even after changing the ballast, the new tube lights in that fixture lasted for 6 months and then flickered and stopped working.

Today we called an electrician and he said that the single switch that turns on these two fixtures was "hot" (showed live current) even after the switch was turned off. He made a change in the junction box to fix this. He took the two pairs of white wires, and put all four together in a single connector. He ensured us that the switch was not "hot" anymore. He asked us to try a single tube light into each of the two fixtures and see for a couple of months whether the lights lasted or not.

I have the following questions and will appreciate your insights:

1. Did the "hot" switch cause of the tube lights to burn out?
2. Would the fix that has been put in work for us? Should we try out with new tube lights?
3. Is there a solution to fix this problem, something that has been overlooked?

Comment: "*Is there a solution to fix this problem, something that has been overlooked?*"  Did the electrician not fix it?    Perhaps it is time to stop throwing money at it, and invest in LED replacements.

Comment: @AlaskaMan while I agree that LEDs are cool (like "kewl", not "not warm"), they're not necessarily the answer to everything. Seems like there's a wiring issue, as fluorescent bulbs shouldn't burn out after only 6 months...

Comment: I can't even tell whether these are fluorescents or LED replacements.  I suspect misapplication of some kind (T12 tubes on T8 ballast, direct-wire LED on ballast, etc.)  OP we will need photos of the ballast labeling and any writing on the tubes.